# Convert NSDictionary to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, json, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have this code:

```
NSDictionary *jsonGuardado = [self dictionaryFromJson:JSON];
NSLog(@"HOLA %@",jsonGuardado);
NSMutableArray *arrayCodigos = [jsonGuardado objectForKey:@"code"];
codigos = arrayCodigos;
```

(Codigos is an NSMutableArray)

The NSLOG return this:

```
HOLA (
        {
        code = 22051310;
    },
        {
        code = 22051311;
    },
        {
        code = 22051312;
    },
        {
        code = 22051313;
    }
)
```

But right after this, a message error says:

`-[JKArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

I search this error in Google and here and all the questions I found not help me.

I'm using the `JSONKit` for make the dictionaryFromJson method.

Comment: Edit your question properly.. there is some mismatch of names. `HOLA` is not a dictionary it is an array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You try this,

```
NSArray *jsonGuardado = [self dictionaryFromJson:JSON];
NSLog(@"HOLA %@",jsonGuardado);
NSMutableArray *arrayCodigos = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[jsonGuardado valueForKey:@"code"]];
NSLog(@"arrayCodigos %@", arrayCodigos);
```

It will print only values.

Comment: This work but I had to change the dictionaryFromJson to arrayFromJson and the return type of the methdod to (NSArray *)

Comment: Yes, I used the same for your understanding :)

Answer (score 2):

The parser returns an array and not a dictionary in your case.

`[self dictionaryFromJson:JSON]` returns a Json array but you are capturing it in NSDictionary

Comment: I'm using this method     -(NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromJson:(NSString *) JSONString {
    JSONDecoder * decoder = [[JSONDecoder alloc] initWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionNone];
return [decoder mutableObjectWithData:[JSONString JSONData]];
}

Comment: if ([[self dictionaryFromJson:JSON] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {}

Answer (score 1):

Your log says that it's already `NSArray`. You should try below

```
NSMutableArray *jsonGuardado = [NSMutableArray array];
jsonGuardado = (id)[self dictionaryFromJson:JSON];
NSLog(@"HOLA %@",jsonGuardado);
NSMutableArray *arrayCodigos = [[jsonGuardado objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"code"];
codigos = [arrayCodigos copy];
NSLog(@"Array %@",codigos);
```